# Internet Connection losing

Tags: windows-7, adsl, internet-connection

When my internet connection is idle for a while about 5 mins, the connection will be lost. It merely happens when the connection is idle, not during download. I'm using an ADSL service by a `HUAWEI smartAX MT882a` ADSL modem.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your router settings for an option for keeping the connection alive. In my router (Buffalo) it's under: Advanced -> PPP Connection.

Alternatively, it could be something your ISP does, although this is unlikely. If you can't find the settings in your router give them a ring and they should be able to help you out more than we can :)

Edit: sorry, just realised you said you had a modem. In which case I would ring my ISP, as your modem is unlikely to have a configuration option for this.

Answer (score 1):

Is your modem configured to keep connection alive?

Comment: @WooYek, Thanks for your response. But I couldn't find a similar setting.